# Determining the wavelength of the eigenfunctions of momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavelength

Self studying QM and working through an example of eigenfunctions of a continuous spectrum - the momentum operator, $\hat{p}$. In the example we've derived the normalized eigenfunctions to be

> $f_{p}(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}$

The book then remarks that we have a sinusoidal function with wavelength $\lambda = \frac{2\pi\hbar}{p}$

My question is: is this wavelength derived from the result of $f_{p}(x)$? Or are we just using the normal formula for the momentum of a particle which is $\lambda = \frac{\hbar}{p}$, in which case where does the extra factor of $2\pi$ come from? I know it's not from the difference between $h$ and $\hbar$ because both formulae use $\hbar$. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wavelength of $e^{i k x}$ is $\lambda = 2\pi / k$. Then, setting $p=\hbar k$, this equation implies $\lambda = 2\pi \hbar / p = h/p$.

One way to see that $\lambda=2\pi/k$ is to note that if we shift $x$ by one wavelength, we should get the same value of the wavefunction (by definition of a wavelength), so $\lambda$ should satisfy the equation $e^{ikx} = e^{i k (x + \lambda)}$. Now, we know that $e^{i \theta} = e^{i (\theta + 2\pi )}$. Comparing this to the equation for $\lambda$, we find that $k \lambda = 2\pi$ or $\lambda = 2\pi / k$.

Another way to see this is to use
\begin{equation}
e^{i k x} = \cos k x + i \sin k x
\end{equation}
and plot $\cos k x$ and $\sin k x$ for a few values of $k$, for example using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sin+%28x%29+and+sin%282+x%29+from+x+%3D+0+to+x+%3D+2*pi). If you try it, you'll see the wavelength is $2\pi/k$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thanks for the explanation and providing multiple perspectives on the answer.